# Clean up the tags [separator] and [divider]

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

It seems that [divider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/divider) is used primarily for Android questions. There is also a [separator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/separator) which is used for all sorts of things.

How can these tags be cleaned up? Should the divider tag be made more specific? Both could use more of a focus, including having their tag descriptions being updated.

Comment: I just found [tag:divider], this time used as a proxy for `div`, as in the HTML element o_O.

Comment: Another clear question...